# How to reuse a list of commands in a gitlab-ci.yaml file for gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab CI job whose `gitlab-ci.yaml` file looks like this:

```
check_1:
  stage: checks
  image: python:3.8-buster
  script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y unzip curl software-properties-common  vim git python3-pip python3
    - curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub -o /tmp/google.pub
    - cat /tmp/google.pub | apt-key add -
    - rm /tmp/google.pub
    - echo 'deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
    - mkdir -p /usr/share/desktop-directories
    - apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
    - dpkg-divert --add --rename --divert /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome.real /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
    - echo -e "#!/bin/bash\nexec /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome.real --no-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox \"\$@\"" > /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
    - chmod 755 /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
    - google-chrome --version
    - wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/91.0.4472.101/chromedriver_linux64.zip && unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
    - export PATH=`pwd`:${PATH}
    - run actual test here

check_2:
  stage: checks
  image: python:3.8-buster
  script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y unzip curl software-properties-common  vim git python3-pip python3
    - curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub -o /tmp/google.pub
    - cat /tmp/google.pub | apt-key add -
    - rm /tmp/google.pub
    - echo 'deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
    - mkdir -p /usr/share/desktop-directories
    - apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
    - dpkg-divert --add --rename --divert /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome.real /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
    - echo -e "#!/bin/bash\nexec /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome.real --no-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox \"\$@\"" > /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
    - chmod 755 /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
    - google-chrome --version
    - wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/91.0.4472.101/chromedriver_linux64.zip && unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
    - export PATH=`pwd`:${PATH}
    - run other test here
```

as you can see, I define two jobs which have the same setup.

Is there a way to define the commands for this setup once, and re-use that definition, instead of having the exact same commands listed twice in the `.gitlab-ci.yaml` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use [yml anchors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#yaml-anchors-for-scripts) if you want keep it all in one file:

```
.reusable-script: &reusable-script
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y unzip curl software-properties-common  vim git python3-pip python3
    - curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub -o /tmp/google.pub
    - cat /tmp/google.pub | apt-key add -
    - rm /tmp/google.pub
    - echo 'deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
    - mkdir -p /usr/share/desktop-directories
    - apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
    - dpkg-divert --add --rename --divert /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome.real /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
    - echo -e "#!/bin/bash\nexec /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome.real --no-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox \"\$@\"" > /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
    - chmod 755 /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
    - google-chrome --version
    - wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/91.0.4472.101/chromedriver_linux64.zip && unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
    - export PATH=`pwd`:${PATH}
    - run actual test here

check_1:
  stage: checks
  image: python:3.8-buster
  script:
    - *reusable-script

check_2:
  stage: checks
  image: python:3.8-buster
  script:
    - *reusable-script
```

Another option would be working with [include](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#include), and put the duplicate script in another file which enables you to use it other projects as well. Then you can use [reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#reference-tags).

.reusable-script.yml

```
.reusable-script: 
  script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y unzip curl software-properties-common  vim git python3-pip python3
    - curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub -o /tmp/google.pub
    - cat /tmp/google.pub | apt-key add -
    - rm /tmp/google.pub
    - echo 'deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
    - mkdir -p /usr/share/desktop-directories
    - apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
    - dpkg-divert --add --rename --divert /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome.real /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
    - echo -e "#!/bin/bash\nexec /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome.real --no-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox \"\$@\"" > /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
    - chmod 755 /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
    - google-chrome --version
    - wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/91.0.4472.101/chromedriver_linux64.zip && unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
    - export PATH=`pwd`:${PATH}
    - run actual test here
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
include:
  local: '.reusable-script.yml'

check_1:
  stage: checks
  image: python:3.8-buster
  script:
    - !reference [.reusable-script, script]

check_2:
  stage: checks
  image: python:3.8-buster
  script:
    - !reference [.reusable-script, script]
```